# Reopen an [on hold] question

Tags: bug, support

The new feature of **[on hold]** instead of **[close]** is great, but maybe it's not fully implemented yet. As of now, we put questions *on hold* to encourage editing, but when the question should be nominated for not being *on hold*, we call it [reopen](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/41349/what-is-the-purpose-and-origin-of-in-page-navigation#). Is there a specific reason for this or is it just a labeling mistake?

[image: reopen voting]

Reference question: [What is the purpose and origin of in-page navigation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/41349/4679)

Comment: So, I guess my question back to you would be - what should the option be called? 'un-on-hold', 'de-hold', 're-activate'? I wouldn't be surprised if, having looked over the syntactical options, we end up back at 'well, reopen isn't too bad after all'.

Comment: LOL I agree to that @JonW, it might be the correct label. Still it feels wrong to reopen something that isn't closed. Looking at suggestions doesn't give the proper meaning either ["advanced, forwarded, furthered, hastened, hurried"](http://www.opposite-word.com/o/on%20hold). If i had to chose, it would be simply **activate** since on hold is also inactive. The community may have a better label, let's ask them of an alternative?!

Comment: The label does matter but let's not forget what is actually happening: The question might be called “on hold” to encourage editing but it really is closed (can't be answered, will look like it was not a good question, etc.) so we need to act accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

**"On Hold" questions actually *are* closed**, so it makes sense to be able to reopen them. "On Hold" means "Closed, but may be re-opened".

Comment: I could agree to that, that the questions are closed, but we call them something else to make them less frightning for new users.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because we have not changed the labels. It is still 'close'/'close votes' and 'reopen'/'reopen votes'. Which, I think, should be changed everywhere too.

[image]

Comment: I don't really agree with changing the "close" button label. You're still voting that it should be be closed. There's just a "waiting period" before closure looks final now.

Comment: @BenBrocka Ah, ok. So it's Vote to close -> Hold -> Reopen and Vote to close -> Hold -> Closed -> Reopen

Comment: Yeah things will eventually convert to a "closed" state. The weirdness is the "reopen" verb doesn't match up with the present state of the "hold" question in a sense. Though it's still technically all the same thing; the only difference between "hold" and "closed" is how long it's been since the question was put on hold